# Issue with Android Spinner inside RecyclerView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-spinner, android-flexboxlayout

I have an issue with showing RecyclerView elements inside RecyclerView.

When I selected the item inside prelast Spinner(1st pic), the last one (Spinner) disappeared(2nd pic.). What could be the main reason?

Every word is TextView. LayoutManager for inner RecyclerView is FlexboxLayoutManager with FlexDirection.ROW.

[image: New fragment]

[image: Here spinner disappears]

Comment: probably it moved to the next line

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko but there are no any lines to the bottom of list

Comment: Make sure you are using 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0' as dependency. I had faced the same problem when I used an older version.